# How to build several left join query in Entity Framework Core for several many to one related entities

Tags: c#, left-join, entity-framework-core

Defined model and classes

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            modelBuilder.Entity<RootLink>()
                .HasOne(link => link.Node)
                .WithMany(node => node.RootLinks)
                .HasForeignKey(link => link.NodeId);

            modelBuilder.Entity<RootLink>()
                .HasOne(link => link.RootNode)
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey(rootLink => rootLink.RootNodeId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

            modelBuilder.Entity<NodeLink>()
                .HasOne(link => link.Node)
                .WithMany(node => node.NodeLinks)
                .HasForeignKey(link => link.NodeId);

            modelBuilder.Entity<NodeLink>()
                .HasOne(l => l.LinkedNode)
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey(l => l.LinkedNodeId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
        }
```

...

```
 public class Node
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }

        public ICollection<RootLink> RootLinks { get; set; }

        public ICollection<NodeLink> NodeLinks { get; set; }

        public int Value { get; set; }
    }

    public class NodeLink
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public long NodeId { get; set; }
        public Node Node { get; set; }

        public long LinkedNodeId { get; set; }
        public Node LinkedNode { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootLink
    {
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public long NodeId { get; set; }
        public Node Node { get; set; }

        public long RootNodeId { get; set; }
        public Node RootNode { get; set; }
    }
```

DB populated as followed:

```
var node1 = new Node();
            var node2 = new Node();
            var node3 = new Node();

            node1.NodeLinks = new List<NodeLink>()
            {
                new NodeLink
                {
                    Node = node1,
                    LinkedNode = node2
                },
                new NodeLink
                {
                    Node = node3,
                    LinkedNode = node3
                }
            };

            node1.RootLinks = new List<RootLink>
            {
                new RootLink {RootNode = node1},
                new RootLink {RootNode = node3}
            };

            ctx.Nodes.AddRange(node1, node2, node3);
```

Thr question is how can I query nodes with it nodeLinks and rootLinks in one query using EF core?

In plain sql it will looks like this:

```
SELECT [node].[Id], [node].[Value], [rootLink].[Id], [rootLink].[NodeId], [rootLink].[RootNodeId]
FROM [Nodes] AS [node]
LEFT JOIN [RootLinks] AS [rootLink] ON [node].[Id] = [rootLink].[NodeId]
LEFT JOIN [NodeLinks] AS [nodeLink] ON [node].[Id] = [rootLink].[NodeId]
WHERE [node].[Id] in (NODE_ID_LIST)
ORDER BY [node].[Id]
```

Using ef i ended up with following variants of query:

```
    public static IEnumerable<Node> FindVariant1(TestDbContext ctx, params long[] nodeIdList)
    {
        return ctx.Nodes
            .Include(node => node.NodeLinks)
            .Include(node => node.RootLinks)
            .Where(node => nodeIdList.Contains(node.Id)).ToList();
    }
    public static IEnumerable<Node> FindVariant2(TestDbContext ctx, params long[] nodeIdList)
    {
        return ctx.Nodes
            .GroupJoin(ctx.RootLinks, node => node.Id, rootLink => rootLink.NodeId,
                (node, rootLinks) => new {node, rootLinks})
            .SelectMany(info => info.rootLinks.DefaultIfEmpty(), (info, rootLink) => new {info.node, rootLink})
            .GroupJoin(ctx.NodeLinks, node => node.node.Id, nodeLink => nodeLink.NodeId,
                (info, nodeLinks) => new {info.node, info.rootLink, nodeLinks})
            .SelectMany(info => info.nodeLinks.DefaultIfEmpty(),
                (info, nodeLink) => new {info.node, info.rootLink, nodeLink})
            .Where(node => nodeIdList.Contains(node.node.Id)).ToList()
            .Select(r => r.node);
    }
```

Both generates several queries.

Comment: Nice question. I'm looking at the first variant with the `.Include`s and trying to slightly change the model (still without success, *till now*).

Answer (score 0):

This answer is based on the [fact](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7082510/6298965) that

> If you have proper indexes, most of the time the EXISTS will perform
>   identically to the JOIN. The exception is on very complicated
>   subqueries, where it is normally quicker to use EXISTS.
>
> If your JOIN key is not indexed, it may be quicker to use EXISTS but
>   you will need to test for your specific circumstance.

So, I'm *assuming* that the clause with `EXISTS` would be an *acceptable* replacement of the `JOIN`.

I've defined the model with a **lambda** in the `WithOne`, reading [this](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/blob/5e1c562ae40c16ef49b90731fd015eccce0c1d44/test/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.FunctionalTests/QueryBugsTest.cs) unit test for customer vs orders.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<RootLink>().ToTable("RootLinks");
modelBuilder.Entity<NodeLink>().ToTable("NodeLinks");
modelBuilder.Entity<Node>().HasKey(r => r.NodeId);

modelBuilder.Entity<Node>()
    .HasMany(link => link.NodeLinks)
    .WithOne(
    l => l.Node
    ).HasForeignKey(l => l.NodeId);


modelBuilder.Entity<Node>()
    .HasMany(link => link.RootLinks)
    .WithOne(
    l => l.Node
    ).HasForeignKey(l => l.NodeId);
```

My query

```
var test = ctx.Nodes
    .Where(n => new long[] { 1, 2 }.Contains( n.NodeId))
    .Include(c => c.NodeLinks)
    .Include(c => c.RootLinks);

 var myRes = test.ToList();
```

The SQL (I've also added some irrelevant name fields)

```
SELECT "n"."NodeId", "n"."Value"
FROM "Nodes" AS "n"
WHERE "n"."NodeId" IN (1, 2)
ORDER BY "n"."NodeId"Executed DbCommand (0ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SELECT "r"."RootLinkId", "r"."NodeId", "r"."RootName"
FROM "RootLinks" AS "r"
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM "Nodes" AS "n"
    WHERE "n"."NodeId" IN (1, 2) AND ("r"."NodeId" = "n"."NodeId"))
ORDER BY "r"."NodeId"Executed DbCommand (0ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SELECT "n0"."NodeLinkId", "n0"."LinkName", "n0"."NodeId"
FROM "NodeLinks" AS "n0"
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM "Nodes" AS "n"
    WHERE "n"."NodeId" IN (1, 2) AND ("n0"."NodeId" = "n"."NodeId"))
ORDER BY "n0"
```

Comment: Initial model is executed with the same query as in your answer. That is the problem - 3 separate queries. I use SQL Server and when I sniff commands through SQL Profiler i see 3 batch commands executed (one for each query). It means there are 3 separete requests to SQL Server. Even keeping in mind connection pooling - this is not looks like optimal way.

Comment: Btw, i wasnt able to update db with you model before i added ".OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);" on each FK declaration. Error message was "Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_RootLinks_Nodes_RootNodeId' on table 'RootLinks' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints."

Comment: As far as the exists clause is equivalent to a join, I don't see a real need to optimize this sql, or at least that should be numerically proved. BTW I was able to update my db (inserting and deleting records) with my model, as it is written in my answer.

Comment: You right about proving of perfomance, i'll try later. Thanks for your time

Comment: fyi I'm using sqlite: maybe that could explain the different behaviour for the foreign key... ? so that would be a sql server (and not EF core) specific error...

Comment: likely, this is why i mentioned that nuanse